# Missing the message status when saving Node

Tags: nodes

Of the handful of content types on our site, some of them don't display the message status (ex. **Article *Test* has been created**) when the node is saved.

Where can I investigate the cause?

Answer (score 1):

This message comes from node.pages.inc ([never edit Drupal core](https://www.drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core)) in a form submit function and I believe messages are stored in the `$_SESSION['messages']` variable. I would try to get at these with a hook_form_alter() and custom validation and submit handlers to see where it might be dropping.

If you're running any custom code look specifically for interactions with the $_SESSION variable. Clobbering or unsetting it could prematurely remove these messages.

If you use the [devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) you can simply use the following.

```
dd($_SESSION['messages']); //Logs to drupal logs
dpm($_SESSION['messages']); //Outputs debug information to screen
```

You can also create your own messages using [drupal_set_message](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7)()

For example:

```
drupal_set_message(t('It worked!'), 'status');
```

You may also want to check that you don't have something like the [Disable Messages module](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) installed or misconfigured.

Comment: Also, I would check the theme is really printing those messages.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be necessary to insert a `drupal_get_messages()` statement in `hook_node_insert()`, `hook_node_submit()` or if you are using tpl files for the nodes then place that in the tpl file or any form callbacks. Not sure why it would work for other content types but not others though.